# Conditional 'AND' 'OR' in SQL where statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm currently making a stored procedure which offers the user a filter system to drill down. Now I'm stumped at trying to put in a conditional clause in the where statement. As seen below:

```
 WHERE upper(stk.warehouse) LIKE '%' + upper(@warehouse) + '%' AND
       upper(stk.product) LIKE '%' + upper(@product) + '%' AND
       upper(stk.description) LIKE '%' + upper(@description) + '%' AND
       upper(stk.long_description) LIKE '%' + upper(@longdescription) + '%' AND
       cast(safety_stock_level as decimal(20)) LIKE '%' +
       upper(@barcode) + '%' AND        
       (stk.physical_qty + stk.on_order_qty -stk.allocated_qty - stk.back_order_qty -
       stk.uninspected_qty)>@available AND

    *if @or =0 BEGIN
    stk.on_order_qty > @onorder AND stk.physical_qty > @phys 
    else
    stk.on_order_qty > @onorder OR stk.physical_qty > @phys*
```

Now I've tried an if statement to no prevail and also a case statement. Is having a conditional OR or AND statement even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
((@or = 0 AND stk.on_order_qty > @onorder AND stk.physical_qty > @phys) OR
 (@or = 1 AND (stk.on_order_qty > @onorder OR stk.physical_qty > @phys)))
```

Comment: Ha, how did I not see it was that simple. Thank you Daniel!!